# Python 2.7: Return the total amount of lines with more than 5 words

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code was just given on the blackboard as an example in class, but when I try to execute it in python (we work with 2.7), it doesn't work.
The code is supposed to read all lines in the text file administration, each line can consist of digits only or characters only. If the line contains no digits and more than 5 words, the number_of_long_lines is increased by 1.
However, in number_of_words, the value of return doesn't go higher than 1 and thus def long(line) always returns false and the output of print number_of_long_lines stays stuck at 0. In this example, the output of print number_of_long_lines should be 3. Where does this code go wrong?

```
LONG_LINE_BORDER = 5
file = open('administration')
input = file.read()
lines = input.splitlines()

print(lines)

def word(string):
    for c in string:
        if not c.isalpha():
            return False
    return True

def number_of_words(line):
    strings = line.split()
    for string in strings:
        result = 0
        if word(string):
            result += 1
    return result

def long(line):
    return number_of_words(line) > LONG_LINE_BORDER

number_of_long_lines = 0

for line in lines:
    if long(line):
        number_of_long_lines += 1
print number_of_long_lines
```

Administration input file:

```
a b c d
a b c d e f
a b c d e f g
5 6 7 3
1 2 3 4 5 6
a b c d e f g h
```

Comment: You reset `result = 0` for each word in the line.  Move that outside of the containing loop.

Comment: using a debugger will help you find the mistake.

Comment: @0x5453 that solved the problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You re-define a 0 value for your result before every call of your `word()` function. Get `result = 0` out of the for loop

```
LONG_LINE_BORDER = 5
file = open('administration')
input = file.read()
lines = input.splitlines()

print(lines)

def word(string):
    for c in string:
        if not c.isalpha():
            return False
    return True

def number_of_words(line):
    strings = line.split()
    result = 0 #put this here
    for string in strings:  
        if word(string):
            result += 1
    return result

def long(line):
    return number_of_words(line) > LONG_LINE_BORDER

number_of_long_lines = 0

for line in lines:
    if long(line):
        number_of_long_lines += 1
print number_of_long_lines
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense